# How to retrieve data from remote server faster in java?

Tags: java

I have a enhanced for loop that enters ch.ethz.ssh2.connection to obtain over 200 values. Every time it goes into the loop a new server is being authenicated and it only retrieves one value from that server. Each time it's looped the data are being saved into an arraylist to be displayed in html tables using thymeleaf. But this method takes forever for eclipse to run through all 200 values one at a time, then it have to restart when I open up localhost:8080 to load up all the tables with all the data. It takes over 5 mins to load the page up. What can I do to speed things up?

**Problem in code**

```
List<DartModel> data = new ArrayList<DartModel>();
for(String server:serverArray) {    

    try {

        conn = new ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection(server);
        conn.connect();
        boolean isAuthenticated = conn
                .authenticateWithPassword(username_array[j],
                        password_array[j]);
        if (isAuthenticated == false) {
            throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");
        }
```

I need to somehow recode the code above so I can obtain the data all in super quickly.

**Output**

```
Loop1: Server1
Loop2: DifferentServer2
Loop3: AllDifferentSever3
and goes on......
```

**Alternative**

I was thinking to let the java program run several times while saving the data into redis. Then Auto refresh the program, when it runs it sends the data into redis. Set an expiration time, But I was unable to get the data into thymeleaf html tables. Would this work? If so how can I display this into thymeleaf.

Comment: Adding your code would help

Comment: Why are you receiving values over SSH instead of some HTTP API? (since you are loading HTML pages)

Comment: Use FindBugs which gives warnings about string+ and such. Profiling would make sense.

Comment: How can I get the program to spit all of the values at once? Each 'sever' is a different value every loop.

Comment: You might be able to use threads to take "chunks" out of the 200 server addresses, but it's not really clear what each thread should be doing.

Comment: @cricket_007 Each thread gets authenticated and retrieve a memory value from ssh. Like memory free.. etc. I have over 200 servers that are being authenticated and running a script to retrieve memory free.

Answer (score 4):

You can query multiple servers at once (in parallel).

If your framework for remote connections is **blocking** (the methods you call actually wait until the response is received), you'd have to start handful of **threads** (one thread for one server in the edge case) to do that in parallel (which doesn't scale very well).

When you can use some **Future/Promise** based tool, you can do it without much overhead (convert 200 futures into one future of 200 values/responses).

Note: In case you would query single server for 200 responses, it is not good idea to do it this way, because you would flood it with too many requests at once. Then you should implement some way to get all the data by one request.

Comment: It wouldn't be a single server. It's basically 200 servers, I connect to each of them to retrieve a data. severarray is the list of 200servers. Thank you for the advice I'll look into future/promise as for now.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:
Create a message protocol that sends all values in one response.

More Info:
Define a simple response message protocol.
One simple example might be this:

```
count,value,...

count: contains the number of values returned.
value: one of the values.
```

Concrete simple example:

```
5,123,234,345,456,567
```

You can go bigger and define the response using json or XML.
Use whatever seems best for your implementation.

**Edit:** My bad, this will not work if you are polling multiple servers.  This solution assumes that you are retrieving 200 values from one server, not one value from 200 servers.

Comment: how would I do that if all the values are in different ssh connections? severArray as a list of 200 servers. Every loop iteration it changes the server name to another server and authenticates it. Then retrieve data

Answer (score 1):

At face value, it's hard to tell without looking at your code (recommend sharing a gist or your code repo).

I assume you are using [library](https://github.com/hudson/ganymed-ssh-2/blob/master/src/main/java/ch/ethz/ssh2/Connection.java). In general, a single SSH2 operation will make several attemtps to authenticate a client. It will iterate over several "methods". I you are using ssh over a command line, you can see these when you use the flag -vv. If one fails, it tries the next. The java library implementation that I found appears to do the same.

In the loop you posted (assuming you loop 200 times), you'll try to authenticate 200 x (authentication method order). I suspect the majority of your execution may be burned in SSH handshakes. This can be avoided by making sure you use your connection only once and get as much as you can from your (already authenticated) opened socket.

Consider moving you connection outside the loop. If you absolutely must do ssh, and the data you are using is too large, parallelism may help some, but that will involve more coordination.

Comment: Yes, basically it authenticates a new server every loop. Where can I find more information about parallelism?

Comment: Parallelism is a concept of relying on multiple running operations concurrently. For optimal situations, you can leverage the cores your hardware (of VM) has.

Comment: I can't move my connection out of the loop because every time the loop iterates it inserts a new server "host name" from a properties file and authenticates it